"tf.summary.image" gives Invalid Argument Error for the standard example
I have recently started Tensorflow by trying to replicate some of the existing repos, and I have been stuck at writing summaries since quite some time now.
Specifically, I have been trying to port the https://github.com/bmild/nerf code to TF2.x. And I realised that

tf.summary.image

doesn't seem to work even with the default examples provided in TF's documentation. - tf.summary.image While I am able to make it work, if the input is scalar, but not for images.
The code:-
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.summary.create_file_writer('test/logs')
with w.as_default():
  image1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 8, 1])
  image2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 8, 1])
  tf.summary.image("grayscale_noise", [image1, image2], step=0)

It throws the following error:-
Exception has occurred: InvalidArgumentError
image must be 3-dimensional[2,8,8,1] [Op:EncodePng]
tensorflow.python.eager.core._NotOkStatusException: InvalidArgumentError: image must be 3-dimensional[2,8,8,1] [Op:EncodePng]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\QYGXAMU\Documents\NeRF\nerf\check_tf_summary.py", line 7, in <module>
    tf.summary.image("grayscale_noise", [image1, image2], step=0)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: image must be 3-dimensional[2,8,8,1] [Op:EncodePng]

Please let me know why this basic snippet is also not working.

Edit: I continued checking the root cause by going into the depths of the library, and found out that there was a clear mismatch between the expected input of image plugin in Tensorboard library and encode_png function of Tensorflow library.
Going through the git commits, release notes and doing comparisons, it's clear that it was indeed one of the changes that was specifically made.
For some reason, despite using tensorflow-gpu=2.3, the tensorboard that was installed was the latest version (as of writing) of 2.17. I downgraded it to 2.13 and everything seems to match properly.
So, in the end, it was just a compatibility issue, and since I was looking at the latest documentation, I was getting confused.
I probably would write a more elucidated answer later on, if needed.
